# Rewrite download csv script to have for loop

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to use a for loop in my code to download multiple files with one click. The problem is that the return statement stops the loop. How can I work around this? Or is there another way to download a csv without the return statement?

EDIT: Rows A6:A30 generate random values. The script checks for duplicates and refreshes the spreadsheet until there are no more duplicates. After this it downloads the csv file and refreshes the spreadsheet. Everytime I click on 'download', it downloads one csv file. I want to repeat this n times, to only have to click once to download 5 different csv files.

```
function createDataUrl(type) {
  const mimeTypes = { csv: MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL, pdf: MimeType.PDF };
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  let url = null;

  for (i=0;i<=5;i++)
  {
  if (type == "csv") {
    url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ss.getId()}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&gid=${sheet.getSheetId()}`;
  } else if (type == "pdf") {
    url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ss.getId()}/export?format=pdf&gid=${sheet.getSheetId()}`;
  }

  while (hasDuplicates('A6:A30')){
    refreshSpreadsheet();
  }

  if (url) {
    const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}` },
    }).getBlob();
    return {
      data:
        `data:${mimeTypes[type]};base64,` +
        Utilities.base64Encode(blob.getBytes()),
      filename: `${sheet.getSheetName()}.${type}`,
    };
  }

  }
  refreshSpreadsheet();
  return { data: null, filename: null };

}
```

index.html

```
<input type="button" value="Download CSV" onclick="download('csv')" />
<!-- <input type="button" value="download as PDF" onclick="download('pdf')" /> -->
<script>
  function download(type) {
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(({ data, filename }) => {
        if (data && filename) {
          const a = document.createElement("a");
          document.body.appendChild(a);
          a.download = filename;
          a.href = data;
          a.click();
        }
      })
      .createDataUrl(type);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: What do you want to return? You could create an array of those objects and append to it and return that after the loop.

Comment: From `I want to use a for loop in my code to download multiple files with one click.`, in your goal, the files are downloaded to the local PC using a HTML? Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: @Tanaike yes, the files are downloaded to the local PC using a HTML. I will put the html code in the post.

Comment: What "multiple files" do you want to download? You are not using the counter in the for loop (`i`) so each iteration will return the same data.

Comment: @Iamblichus I added more code. Rows A6:A30 generate random values. The script checks for duplicates and refreshes the spreadsheet until there are no more duplicates. After this it downloads the csv file and refreshes the spreadsheet. Everytime I click on 'download', it downloads one csv file. I want to repeat this n times, to only have to click once to download 5 different csv files.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I saw your question, I couldn't find whethr using ZIP is includedin your goal. So, when this is not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, how about zipping those CSV files? When this is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function createDataUrl(type) {
  const mimeTypes = { csv: MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL, pdf: MimeType.PDF };
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  let url = null;
  var blobs = [];
  for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    if (type == "csv") {
      url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ss.getId()}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&gid=${sheet.getSheetId()}`;
    } else if (type == "pdf") {
      url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ss.getId()}/export?format=pdf&gid=${sheet.getSheetId()}`;
    }
    while (hasDuplicates('A6:A30')) {
      refreshSpreadsheet();
    }
    if (url) {
      const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}` } }).getBlob();
      blobs.push(blob);
    }
  }
  if (blobs.length > 0) {
    return {
      data:
        `data:${MimeType.ZIP};base64,` +
        Utilities.base64Encode(Utilities.zip(blobs).getBytes()),
      filename: `${sheet.getSheetName()}.zip`,
    };
  }
  refreshSpreadsheet();
  return { data: null, filename: null };
}
```

#### Reference:

- [zip(blobs)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#zipblobs)